# Cant repeat switch statement in java

Tags: java, switch-statement, console-application

I am developing a simple banking application in java for my computer Science class, but am unable to repeat a switch statement. Here is my switch statement. Thanks!

```
//Menu
System.out.println("W. Withdraw");
System.out.println("D. Deposit");
System.out.println("B. View Balance");
System.out.println("To exit program, type Quit");

Scanner keyboardMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
menuOptions = keyboardMenu.next();

//Switch statement to navigate menu options
switch (menuOptions) {
    case "B": 
        System.out.println("Your balance is $" + balance);
        break;
    case "D":
        System.out.println("Deposit: ");
        Scanner keyboardDeposit = new Scanner(System.in);
        double deposit = keyboardDeposit.nextDouble();
        balance = balance + deposit;
        System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + balance);
        break;
    case "W":
        System.out.println("Withdraw: ");
        Scanner keyboardWithdraw = new Scanner(System.in);
        double withdraw = keyboardWithdraw.nextDouble();
        balance = balance - withdraw;
        System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + balance);
        break;
    case "Quit":
        System.out.println("Program terminated.");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Please select an option.");
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "repeat?"  Do you want it in a loop or something?

Comment: Yes. I tried a while loop but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: You should edit the question to show a potential solution you've tried, and/or what error you might have gotten.  This question is kind of a "How do you do X" question.  StackOverflow is more for "Why do I get this error" questions.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context, I am going to assume that you are trying to do something like this:

```
do{
    System.out.println("W. Withdraw");
    System.out.println("D. Deposit");
    System.out.println("B. View Balance");
    System.out.println("To exit program, type Quit");
    Scanner keyboardMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
    menuOptions = keyboardMenu.next();
    boolean keepGoing = true; 
   //Switch statement to navigate menu options
   switch (menuOptions) {
case "B": 
       System.out.println("Your balance is $" + balance);
       break;
case "D":
       System.out.println("Deposit: ");
       Scanner keyboardDeposit = new Scanner(System.in);
    double deposit = keyboardDeposit.nextDouble();
    balance = balance + deposit;
    System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + balance);
    break;
case "W":
    System.out.println("Withdraw: ");
    Scanner keyboardWithdraw = new Scanner(System.in);
    double withdraw = keyboardWithdraw.nextDouble();
    balance = balance - withdraw;
    System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + balance);
    break;
case "Quit":
    System.out.println("Program terminated.");
    keepGoing = false; 
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("Please select an option.");
    break;
}while(keepGoing)
```

Comment: When I attempt to view balance I am presented with a infinite loop, also when I withdraw, I can only withdraw after and not perform other actions.

Comment: I updated the code. It's just a do-while loop that you use and end when you need to. So feel free to adjust it as needed. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would pull the Quit clause out of the switch, then wrap your other functions in a `While` loop.  Something like:

```
//Switch statement to navigate menu options
while (menuOptions != "Quit") {
    switch (menuOptions) {
        case "B": 
            System.out.println("Your balance is $" + balance);
            break;
        case "D":
            System.out.println("Deposit: ");
            double deposit = keyboardDeposit.nextDouble();
            balance = balance + deposit;
            System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + balance);
            break;
        case "W":
            System.out.println("Withdraw: ");
            double withdraw = keyboardWithdraw.nextDouble();
            balance = balance - withdraw;
            System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + balance);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please select an option.");
            break;
    } 
    menuOptions = keyboardMenu.next();
}
System.out.println("Program terminated.");
```

So, each time when you go into the switch, you're sure they haven't typed Quit.  Then, at the end of the day, when they HAVE typed Quit, you break into the Program Terminated line.

I would also put your `new Scanner` after the `Switch` statement.  That way you only have to call it once... after you've done your decision tree.